# Property 'cash' does not exist on type 'Document<unknown, {}, Schema<any, Model...>

Tags: typescript, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have connected a mongo db database to my discord bot, and made a economy system, but i get this error when i try to get the money in a user's wallet/bank. A few hours ago it worked just fine, but for some reason it broke. I also get a DeprecationWarning from mongodb.

```
Property 'cash' does not exist on type 'Document<unknown, {}, Schema<any, Model<any, any, any, any, any, any>, {}, {}, {}, {}, DefaultSchemaOptions, { cash: number; bank: number; _id?: ObjectId | null | undefined; userId?: string | ... 1 more ... | undefined; guildId?: string | ... 1 more ... | undefined; }, Document<...> & ... 1 more ... & Required<...>>...'.
```

```
Property 'bank' does not exist on type 'Document<unknown, {}, Schema<any, Model<any, any, any, any, any, any>, {}, {}, {}, {}, DefaultSchemaOptions, { cash: number; bank: number; _id?: ObjectId | null | undefined; userId?: string | ... 1 more ... | undefined; guildId?: string | ... 1 more ... | undefined; }, Document<...> & ... 1 more ... & Required<...>>...'.
```

```
// User.ts
DeprecationWarning: The URL mongodb://USERNAME:..../DiscordBot?authSource=admin&replicaSet=atlas-14ldvb-shard-0&retryWrites=true&w=majority&ssl=true is invalid. Future versions of Node.js will throw an error.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

```
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  _id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId },
  userId: { type: Schema.Types.String },
  guildId: { type: Schema.Types.String },
  cash: { type: Number, required: false, default: 100 },
  bank: { type: Schema.Types.Number, required: false, default: 0 },
});

export default model<typeof UserSchema>("User", UserSchema, "users");;
```

```
// balance.ts

import {
  ChatInputCommandInteraction,
  EmbedBuilder,
  SlashCommandBuilder,
} from "discord.js";
import Client from "../../classes/Client";
import { Colors } from "../../types";
import { getUserProfile } from "../../helpers/getUserProfile";

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("balance")
    .setDescription(`Check your or someone else's balance`)
    .addUserOption((opt) =>
      opt
        .setName("member")
        .setDescription("Member you want to see balance of")
        .setRequired(false)
    ),
  execute: async (interaction: ChatInputCommandInteraction, client: Client) => {
    const member =
      interaction.options.getUser("member", false) || interaction.user;
    const userProfile = await getUserProfile(member.id, interaction.guildId!);
    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setAuthor({
        name: `${member.username}'s balance`,
        iconURL: member.displayAvatarURL(),
      })
      .setDescription(
        `**Wallet**: \`$${userProfile.cash}\`\n**Bank**: \`$${userProfile.bank}\`` // <- this is the line with the error
      )
      .setColor(Colors.EmbedBackground);

    interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
  },
};
```

I saw on google that someone had the same issue, he changed his password and it worked but it didn't work for me

Comment: Could you include the code for `getUserProfile`?

Comment: I fixed the error and I found out that the warning was caused by a package called discord-xp that should make life easier when it comes to making a leveling system. In order to use that package, i need to set the mongodb uri for it, and that was giving the warning, but since i don't want to make a xp system from scratch, I guess i'll just leave it like this. Also i saw some stuff about node versions, so i changed  my version from 20 to 21, but the warning was still there and a new one appeared. After that i tried downgrading to node 18, which fixed the warning.

Comment: I'm sure that downgrading my node  version isn't the best  thing to do but that was the only fix I found, and i dont see any errors right now  so im going to leave it like  this for now